# Merge 2 xcode projects

Tags: delegates, merge, master-detail

I have 2 xcode projects and i want to merge them into 1. But i stucked at the Delegates as both project has their own delegates.
First project has a Splitview (Master/Detail) view and the second project is a carousel.

I want to replace the detail view with the carousel project. I already linked the framework and the related files and nibs.

But im stucked at the appdelegate of the MasterDetail, how do i call the appdelegate and the ViewController of the carousel project and pass the selected item to the carousel?

```
#import "iPadAppDelegate.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

//iCarousel
#import "CarouselExampleAppDelegate.h"
#import "CarouselExampleViewController.h"
//

@implementation iPadAppDelegate

@synthesize window, splitViewController, masterViewController, detailViewController;

//iCarousel
@synthesize carouselExampleViewController;
//

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    

    masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

    /*
    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
    */



    **//iCarousel
    ??? Call the Carousel delegate? And also the Carousel Controller?
    //**

    splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;


    // Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks,

Kevin